# Is there a contradiction in coin toss of expected / actual results?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

There is the task on probability:

*We have a fair coin and we intend to make 8 coin toss. After 4 coin tosses we have 3 Tails and 1 Head, what is the expected result after all 8 coin tosses.*

**Answer** 5 Tails, 3 Heads, since one can expect those 4 coin tosses to be 50/50.

At the same time we know that for large numbers we need to have 50/50 probability, regardless of temporary overweight of one side over other. So Heads "should catch up" with Tails if we toss coin long enough.

But isn't there a contradiction: On one side we expect to have 50/50 result, on the other we admit that after some overweight we expect rest of the tosses to be 50/50, so this overweight should at least still be present.

Comment: The apparent contradiction just relies on the subtle difference between *probability* and *conditional probabilty*. Roughly speaking, acquiring  knowledge reshapes the probability space.

Comment: Despite what all gamblers would like, there is no "pull to the average".  The future has no memory of the past.

Comment: @lulu so rule 50/50 won't work if there is no "pull to the average" No matter how much we will toss the coin after minor overweight this overweight should remain.

Comment: Of course.  The expected value from the future is exactly what it was before.  There is no contradiction or paradox in any of this.

Comment: The "law of averages" you reference refers to an unbiased start.  If you tell me that you start with a bias, then I expect that bias to persist.  Why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overweight gets smaller and smaller as the amount of tosses gets larger, so taking the limit to infinity this overweight disappears.

$$\frac{x_1+\ldots+x_N+X_{N+1}+\ldots+X_n}{n}=\frac{x_1+\ldots+x_N}{n}+\frac{X_{N+1}+\ldots+X_n}{n}\to 0.5$$ as $n\to\infty$, where we already now the first $N$ outcomes, because $\frac{x_1+\ldots+x_N}{n}\to 0$ and $\frac{X_{N+1}+\ldots+X_n}{n}\to 0.5$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: But coin doesn't "know" that there is an overweight. Let's say in the past we had overweight to Heads side, which means that in the future we need to toss more Tails, which would break 50/50 rule, isn't it?

Comment: @wasd If you know the first $N$ outcomes, then that $N$ stays fixed. Indeed the coin doesn't know that there is an overweight or the past. A large, but finite amount is only close to (not exactly!) 50/50, but the rule states that if you keep throwing then it will converge exactly to 50/50. Like I already said, the overweight (a fixed number $N$ of known outcomes) just gets smaller as you keep throwing coins ($n$ gets bigger).